# Using react-player API causing Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow' error in the console?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-iframe-api

I have installed react-player as recommended by a user here it solved my initial problem but now I have this error in the console on chrome `Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('<URL>') does not match the recipient window's origin ('<URL>').` I don't know what to do about it?
My code is as follows(only snippets of my full code):

```
import React, { useRef, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import ReactPlayer from 'react-player/youtube'

function Webapps() {

const autoplayChange = () => {
        console.log('playing!')
    }
return(
<div className='iframeContainer'><ReactPlayer url={Projects.videoAddress} muted={true} controls={false} onPlay={autoplayChange} onPause={autoplayChange} onEnded={autoplayChange}/></div>
)

}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This error means that you are using a URL that does not match your website's origin / address.

This is called `cross origin resource sharing` and it is a warning in case a website does not permit you to display their content on a different website. Fortunately, youtube does allow you to use their videos. On my end, it looks like the warning is due to their ad-embedded content. The content should otherwise work.

[image]

A CodeSandbox [example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-react-player-youtube-iygks?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: Hi thanks for your response again mate, the errors should be ignored then? 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/-zuxYPJrlmw' here's an example of one of my links stored in Json do you see any issues with it? also thanks for the second tip but it's not stored in an Iframe its just a name I've used on a <div> element for styling.

Comment: I have tried to embed the links the same way you did 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-zuxYPJrlmw' but still the same result

Comment: Oh I see what you did with the `<div>`, that makes sense, I should have read closer! So to summarize, you are seeing the same warning as in my screenshot correct? If so, I think you can safely ignore it. If you are getting an error that is not allowing you to play the video, let me know and let's further debug.

Answer (score 2):

I had to disable my Add-Blocker.